# jquery stopImmediatePropagation does not prevent event from executing function twice

Tags: jquery, keyboard-events

My problem is that code gets executed twice.
I have a textarea that pops up a jquery dialog(when a dot is typed).

```
$('#myText').keydown(function(e){handleKeys(e);});
function handleKeys(e){  if(e.keyCode == 190){openIntelli(e,null);}}
```

When the user keeps typing keys, they are listened to by the widget of the dialog with

```
widget.unbind('keypress');
 widget.on('keypress',function(event)
    {event.stopImmediatePropagation();rearrangeIntelli(event);});
```

In the rearrangeIntelli, the dialog is closed, then the key that was typed was inserted back in the teaxtarea, then the intelli dialog box is opened again with openIntelli()

```
function rearrangeIntelli(event){
    console.log('rearrangeIntelli');
    //event.stopImmediatePropagation();   I tried to put it here, no effect
    //alert('key:'+event.which);

    var key=String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    closeIntelli();

    insertTextAtCursor(key);
    openIntelli(event,key);

}
```

It works fine, untill I want to close the dialog: 
    if(key=='k'){closeIntelli();}

Then it closes , but inserts the last key again, and that's not what I want. I tried to stop it with event.stopImmediatePropagation(); in all possible places. But after closeIntelli, it returns to the widget.keypress(function.., then back to the end of rearrangeIntelli and id adds another key.

I have no idea how to stop this. From roaming a little bit in the jquery side, it seems that it wants to return the result of the rearrangeIntelli function again.But I have no idea what to do to stop it from executing the inserttextAtCursor() twice.

Below is the full code. Can some one please give me a hint. Does it have anything to do with stopPropagation, or do I need to look somewhere else.
Thanks a lot for any help,
Jenita

```
           <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.1.11.0.min.js">        </script>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/jquery.1.11.1.ui.smoothness.css" />
```

```
<script>

    $(function() {    

    $('#myText').keydown(function(e){handleKeys(e);});

      $("#intelli" ).dialog({autoOpen:false});

    $("#intelli" ).dialog({ width: 700,maxHeight:500 }).css({ "font-size": "18px", "font-family":"Times New Roman" } );

    $("#intelli").dialog("option","title","Properties and Methods");


    });


function handleKeys(e){  if(e.keyCode == 190){openIntelli(e,null);}}

function openIntelli(event,key){
        console.log('openIntelli');

         var intelli=$('#intelli');        /// get the intelli dialog


        $("#intelli" ).dialog("open");
        $("#intelli").dialog('option','position',{my: "left top",at: "right top",of: event.target});
        var widget=$('#intelli').dialog('widget');
        widget.unbind('keypress');

        widget.on('keypress',function(event){event.stopImmediatePropagation();rearrangeIntelli(event);});
        widget.focus();


        if(key=='k')
        {
            console.log('from openIntelli:close'); closeIntelli();
             }

        }




    function closeIntelli(){
        console.log('closeIntelli');

        $("#intelli").dialog("close");

    }


function rearrangeIntelli(event){
    console.log('rearrangeIntelli');
    //event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        //alert('key:'+event.which);

    var key=String.fromCharCode(event.which);
        closeIntelli();

        insertTextAtCursor(key);
        openIntelli(event,key);

    }




    function insertTextAtCursor( text) {

        var el=$('#myText')[0];
        console.log('insertTextCursor:'+text);
            var val = el.value, endIndex, range;
        if (typeof el.selectionStart != "undefined" && typeof el.selectionEnd != "undefined") {
            endIndex = el.selectionEnd;
                      }
            console.log('endIndex:'+endIndex);
          el.value = val.slice(0, endIndex) + text + val.slice(endIndex);
            el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = endIndex + text.length;



      }
</script>

<textarea id='myText'></textarea>
<div id='intelli'>hello there</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, when a `k` is pressed, it is handled by the `keypress` handler for the widget. That closes the dialog, adds the `k` to the textarea, and then re-opens the dialog by calling `openIntelli()`. Of course, when `k` is passed to `openIntelli()`, it closes the dialog right away.

If I understand correctly, you do not want the `k` added to the textarea. In that case, check the key in the `keypress` handler for the widget. If the key is a `k`, do not add it to the textarea and do not re-open the dialog.

However, I do not think that it is necessary to close and re-open the dialog for each key. Here is some code that may work for you. See the comments in the code:

```
$(function() {    
    function insertTextAt(el, text, pos) {
        if (typeof pos != 'undefined') {
            var val = el.value;
            el.value = val.slice(0, pos) + text + val.slice(pos);
            el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = pos + text.length;
        } else {
            el.value += text;
            el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = el.value.length;
        }
    }

    function instrumentIntelli($textarea) {
        // Create closure variable for the textarea cursor position.
        var pos;

        // Create the dialog element and instrument it as a dialog.
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Properties and Methods',
            width: 250,
            maxHeight: 100,
            position: {
                my: 'left top',
                at: 'right top',
                of: $textarea[0]
            }
        }).css({
            'font-size': '18px',
            'font-family': 'Times New Roman'
        });

        $dialog.dialog('widget').keypress(function(event) {
            var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
            if (key != 'k') {
                // In some browsers this moves the focus to the textarea.
                insertTextAt($textarea[0], key, pos);

                // Update the cursor position variable.
                pos = $textarea[0].selectionEnd;

                // Move the focus back to the widget.
                $dialog.dialog('widget').focus();
            } else {
                $dialog.dialog('close');

                // Since the dialog will remain closed, we want to move the
                // focus to the textarea, but we want to delay this until
                // after the keyup event is finished or else the textarea
                // will get a keypress event for the key.
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $textarea.focus();
                    $textarea[0].selectionStart = $textarea[0].selectionEnd = pos;
                }, 0);
            }        
        });

        $textarea.keydown(function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 190) {
                // Set the cursor position variable before opening the
                // dialog and moving the focus from the textarea.
                pos = $textarea[0].selectionEnd;

                // Open the dialog and move the focus to the widget.
                $dialog.dialog('open').dialog('widget').focus();
            }
        });
    }

    instrumentIntelli($('#myText'));
});
```

Notice that the `<div>` for the dialog is created dynamically.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d86ovxhr/11/)

Comment: Thanks , I had not seen you update. It still has the problem though that it looses focus after inserttextAtCursor, so the keys are not handled by the widget while the dialog is open even after widget.focus(), which is what I need. Any idea how to keep the focus on the widget?

Comment: @Jenita - I was working on this in Firefox, where the focus does not get lost by calling `insertTextAtCursor`. I see that it behaves quite differently in IE. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks John, I have basically used your set up.  I do close and open the dialog ( to regain focus)and put the rearrangement code in between, but  don't go through the whole openIntelli function again. This setup makes more sense. Thanks for warning me that it works differently in Firefox . I've accepted your answer.